# AWS ELB kills RabbitMQ service in AWS ECS once in a few minutues because of failed health check

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs, aws-elb

I'm running RabbitMQ Docker image (rabbitmq:3-management) in AWS ECS. It's working fine with no issues.

Then I added a bit more complexity and created a service with the same RabbitMQ but now connected to AWS Network Load Balancer (my ultimate goal is to create a RabbitMQ cluster, so I need a few instances behind load balancer). Target group is configured with port 5672 and uses the same port for health checks. *Interval* between health checks is 30 sec (it's max available). *Threshold* is 5.
In configuration of service in ECS *Health check grace period* is 120 sec. Should be enough to start service.
What happens is that when I run service after a few minutes it gets killed and restarted:

```
service Rabbit-master (instance i-xxx) (port 5672) is unhealthy in target-group Rabbit-cluster-target-group due to (reason Health checks failed)
```

*'A few minutes'* means 2 or 5 or 9... It varies. It doesn't happen on a start but after a while.
Also I see that RabbitMQ works fine (in logs and in management panel). So it's exactly ELB which causes its restart. Not that first RabbitMQ died and then ELB restarted it, no.

So my question is what I'm doing wrong and how I can achieve stable work of RabbitMQ in ECS in pair with ELB? Is the idea to use port 5672 for helth checks wrong? But which port then to use? 15672?

Sorry if I provided not enough details. I desribed those which seemed to me relevant. If you need anything more I will be happy to elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the problem was with configuring security group of RabbitMQ service with IP of NLB.
This idea didn't come to me immediately because

1. restarts happened not right away after service run but after a few
   minutues
2. NLB don't have security groups and their IDs are not that
       obvious to find.

More details are here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263245

and here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups

Comment: Thanks for this! I had this exact problem and was reading about this all over the place. And only your comment was concise enough for me to figure out what needs to be done. The problem I'm having right now is I'm opening services to the whole VPC, but I'm not thrilled with that. I can get private NLB IPs from the AWS console, but don't know how to use them in the CDK environment. If you know how to close it down, it would help immensely. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you can use this to get NLB IPs: `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query 'NetworkInterfaces[?contains(Description, NLB-name)].PrivateIpAddresses[*].PrivateIpAddress[]'`. You need to change `NLB-name` with your actual network load balancer name (surrounded by backticks if it is a string), and it should work. For me, it prints two IPs. Haven't tried, but this should be enough to add to the service security group ingress - feel free to correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Thanks! After adding ports to my EKS security group, LB was able to talk to instances in that group!

Answer (score 1):

This is very important to specify the health check path or port when attaching your service with ALB.

ALB does not check the response body but it checks the status code, so the only call that will return you `200` status code is `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:15672`  rest will require authentication or 404 or 403 which LB mark target unhealthy.

[image]

As 15672 will return 200.

[image]

Also, verify the health check of the desired target group of ECS task, does it point the correct port of the instance.
[image]

**2nd Option:** Further, you can write custom health checks for LB which will monitor both port of your container, as ALB check health checks only one port at the time, a simple example can be based on nodejs, so for that its mean you have to run simple node application that will check both port and will response ALB health checks.

In this case, your healthcheck will be `/ping` and port will be `3007`

Below is the code that we use for such ECS task where we need to check multiple port.

```
   var express = require('express');
const isAllReachable = require('is-all-reachable');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {

    isAllReachable([
        // first check if all reachable
        'http://localhost:15672'
        // 'http://localhost:otherport'
    ], (err, reachable, host) => {
        //if reachable then do API request if its responding
        if (reachable) {

            console.log("Health check passed");
            console.log("checking rabbitMQ");
            request.get('http://localhost:15672/api/vhosts', {
                'auth': {
                    'user': 'guest',
                    'pass': 'guest',
                    'sendImmediately': false
                }
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                console.log({
                    "status_code": response.statusCode,
                    "body": body
                })
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    console.log("failed to get vhosts");
                    res.status(500).send('health check failed');
                } else {
                    res.status(200).send('rabbit mq is running');
                }

            })
        } else {
            console.log("health check failed. ", "This server is not reachable", err);
            res.status(500).send('health check failed. one of the port is not reachable.');
            console.log(reachable)
        }
    });
});

    app.listen(3007, () => console.log('LB custom Health check server listening on port 3007!'));
```

For Rabbit monitoring, in deep you can explore [rabbitmq monitoring.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html)

Comment: I use Network Load Balancer which works with TCP, not HTTP. Hence you don't have to (and can't) provide URL for health check. By default it pings given port.

Yes I can add more sophisticated healthcheck to container. Actually I even had one at the beginning of my explorations. It was based on RabbitMQ embedded diagnostics tools. But then I ended up with default port ping since while creating cluster RabbitMQ has to be stopped at some moments. So such health check will fail at this moment, which is not desired behavior.

Comment: so you can set it a health check port 15672, go to your target group and override your health check port, as this port will respond with 200 status code

Comment: The problem was in security groups. It was a bit not obvious with NLB but still.

Plese see my own answer to the question over. :-)

Comment: got it, NLB dont have secuirty gorup its use secuirty group of the instance

Answer (score 0):

Does your healthcheck url works? it happened to me with ALB. My case was

- ex: TargetGroup was mapped to `/api/profiles` => container:4000, but
  my container didnt have any route to server `api/profiles`. Because
  ALB didnt rewrite the path as for ex Nginx. It was searching the
  `api/profiles` route in the container, and my route was just
  `/profiles`. So i changed the path in the nginx then it worked.

How to diagnose

- Enable the cloudwatch logs and then you will see the real issue, hopefully.
- If not go through the whole list here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But I use Network Load Balancer, not ALB. And NLB works with TCP, not HTTP. So it pings given port for health check. It's simply impossible to specify any URL there.